# Getting very low accuracy score on binary crossentropy [Keras]

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I get pretty dismal accuracy scores when training my network with cross entropy loss function in Keras.

For eg. For this model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(GRU(input_dim, input_shape=(params['seqLength'],input_dim), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(GRU(input_dim*2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(input_dim))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

print("Compiling model...")
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])

print("Training...")
(params["resultsDir"], int(time.time())), verbose=1, save_best_only=False)
history = model.fit(X, Y, validation_split=0.2, nb_epoch=20)
```

I get a loss value of about 0.012, but an accuracy value of just 0.021. If this accuracy is converted to percentage, then it is only about 2.1%.
If the loss is log-loss, then `0.012` is pretty good, so why is the accuracy so low?

Comment: Do you by loss value mean loss on a training set or a validation set?

Comment: I suppose Keras scores it on both. I'll read the source and get back to you.